# Hardibacker seems to draw moisture out of thinset?

Tags: tile

Working with 3/4" glass mosaic tiles for the first time - look great, but a very different process than I'm used to with ceramic tiles of normal size.

Tiled a section of cement floor following the glass tile instructions (rake with 1/4 x 3/16 V notch, then trowel flat, then place tile and beat into place) which worked pretty much fine (one loose tile from a few hundred, and several places where I must not have gotten the raking and smoothing even enough so I had to go over with a grout saw to remove excess thinset before grouting.)

Moved on to doing a section of wall that's covered with 1/2" hardibacker. Only did about 3 square feet as I figured it was going to be trickier working on the wall than the floor. Got the thinset on the wall successfully, raked and smooth, tile (in sheets with a gummed paper on the face on it and not falling down, moved to beating it in and I could hear it rattling - much of the mortar wasn't taking the tile, though enough had for the sheets to be on the wall ([Mapei glass tile mortar](https://www.mapei.com/us/en-us/products-and-solutions/products/detail/mosaic-glass-tile-mortar), supposedly 2 hour pot life, 30 minute open time and conditions were not particularly hot or dry.)

I ended up stripping the tiles and scraping off the mortar. As far as I recall [the instructions](https://cdnmedia.mapei.com/docs/librariesprovider10/line-technical-documentation-documents/surface-preparation-requirements.pdf?sfvrsn=fff0161b_4) said nothing about pre-wetting the substrate (I understand Hardibacker to be what they call CBU), but it certainly appeared that the Hardibacker had dried it out to a point of uselessness in a very short period (which the concrete floor did not, but of course the floor needed to be mopped clean before tiling and the walls did not.) I'm wondering if I should pre-wet/dampen the hardibacker before applying thinset.

I basically wasted a few hours and a lot of mortar to re-set that one 3/4" square tile in the floor that had been loose, as opposed to getting started on the wall section...

Back-buttering these tiny tiles seems like it would result in a huge amount of cleanup for grouting if laid on with a trowel, and would be incredibly tedious dotting on the back of each one (225 tiles per sheet.)

[Similar question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/7066/installing-glass-mosaic-backsplash) but not exactly this (mesh rather than paper face and more about trowel technique)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The actual [HardiBacker installation instructions](https://www.jameshardiepros.com/getattachment/98adb0c7-1bd1-49e7-a9d4-a8275d29ae4a/hardiebacker-installation-guide-english-spanish-hb1710.pdf) (page 5) for tile do say to wipe the surface clean "with a damp sponge":

> Wipe the surface of HardieBacker® cement board clean with a damp sponge just prior to adding mastic or mortar.

[image: screenshot of HardieBacker cement board installation instructions for tile]

[This 2006 forum discussion](https://www.johnbridge.com/vbulletin/showthread.php?t=36155) also seems to anecdotally back up that wetting HardieBacker first is a known "must do":

> Hardi is thirsty, thirsty, thirsty. It tends to suck moisture out of thinset NOW and makes working time difficult. Kinda like laying wallpaper on un-sized plaster walls.

and

> Dry backerboard will suck water out of mortar like a sponge. If too much is removed the final bond becomes very weak.